# Remove System.ServiceModel from MvvmCross

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using the Indie license of Xamarin Studio which unfortunately does not include support for System.ServiceModel and my budget does not include support for an additional $700 for the Business license.

I have been following and really like the MvvmCross tutorials but this issue won't let me even compile because MvvmCross references System.ServiceModel.

How can I cleanly remove the System.ServiceModel reference from MvvmCross so I can use it with this handicap?

Thanks!

Comment: Xamarin is the carrot that hangs before the nose of a chaser of the "Grail". Every dollar, or chunk of hundreds of dollars, gets you closer to realizing that there's no "Grail". Hated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been recently (in the last week) reported and a community member has already produced a fix - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/397

It's likely this fix will be tested and released in the next two weeks. Until them you should be able to build this yourself - or you can evaluate the business edition for 1 month.

From the fact this has only recently been reported I guess that xamarin have also recently changed their license-detection code - so you could also ask their support for some assistance with this breaking change - but obviously there are no guarantees that they will assist.

Comment: So as of today, using MvvmCross 3.0.14, it's still referencing the System.ServiceModel thus closing the doors for Indie developers. Is this intentional? Was the fix not possible to pull into the MvvmCross product?

Comment: MvvmCross is open source and is not closing the door to Indie developers. The only remaining assemblies which reference `System.ServiceModel` within the MvvmCross source code are the PCL stubs (which allegedly should no longer be needed) and the imported Json.Net - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/search?q=ServiceModel&ref=cmdform - if you find problems, then I suggest you ask the company you are paying for your Indie license